# textbox inside a gridview lose value on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

in this code when i click on button all other `textboxes` that are on other row of gridview lose their values on postback what should i do ?
button add a new comment to database and rebind the gridview with a `AsyncPostBack`

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>

    <ContentTemplate>
        <%--post GridView--%>
        <asp:GridView ID="posts" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%--Comments Gridview--%>
                        <asp:GridView ID="comments" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
                        <%--a Textbox and bUtton For sending new Comment--%>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel> 


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //add new comment to db here then rebind gv
    posts.DataSource = GetData();
    posts.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the postback that's losing the textbox values, it's the DataBind. Just add the comment to the db without the DataBind.

Comment: but i cant remove post.DataBind(); because i also want o get others comments too !

Comment: OK, but the code you posted doesn't do that. How does the comments grid get populated? Can you edit your post to show the code that does that?

Comment: please see my new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468651/how-do-i-preserve-a-value-entered-in-a-textbox-inside-a-gridviews-templatefield/24468714#24468714